# Insert button in XTemplate Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using the framwork Sencha Touch 2 and now i have a problem when create a List component because i create a XTemplate for this, but i need insert a button component in each element for the list

```
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            id: 'list_product',
            emptyText: '<div class="list-empty-text">No hay coincidencias</div>',
            store: 'Product',
            itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<h3>{name}</h3>' +
                '[{xtype:"button"}]'//Here i tried insert a button
            ),
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    docked: 'top',
                    items: [
                        {xtype: 'spacer'},
                        {
                            xtype: 'searchfield',
                            placeHolder: 'Buscar...'
                        },
                        {xtype: 'spacer'}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

I read the documentation, but i not see a example or some code help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `itemTpl` and `XTemplate` in that manner. Templates are written as HTML, whereas you are mixing HTML and Javascript in your `XTemplate`

```
'<h3>{name}</h3>' + //This is HTML
'[{xtype:"button"}]' //This is Javascript
```

In order to do what you want, you will need to use `dataview` and `dataitem`. For examples of how to use them, consult the Dataview [guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/dataview) and [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView)

Comment: Using dataview,  i can create a searcher component as in the list component?

Comment: Probably. See how it's done for `list`; `list` is a child class of `dataview`. If you need more details, you should create another question.